# Htaccess redirect from 12am to 6pm on a certain date

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to know how I can redirect to a certain page (during maintenance) at a certain date between 12am and 6pm for example.

thanks!
Jasper

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you just add the redirect to your `.htaccess` when you start the maintenance and then remove it when you're done?  Or is this a regularly-scheduled type of thing (in which case see the cron suggestion below)?

Comment: Yes I'm using PHP but we're talking about 5 websites (and still growing) so I would rather like a htaccess-level solution. 
The maintenance happens every wednesday. (and the maintenance happens in the datacenter so I don't want to care about stuff like that and set the htaccess file during office hours, not at night ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a cron job to create/move the .htaccess file and then a second to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

You can program rewrite rules in `.htaccess` to redirect trafic based on time or date.
Look at the 'date and time' variables that you can use on the [rewrite_cond documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

You can compound the different `TIME_` variables to get to a number that you can compare.

For example, to redirect trafic between midnight (00) and 4am (04) every Tuesday (02), you could use

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY}%{TIME_HOUR} > 0200    # IF it's after Tuesday 00
RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY}%{TIME_HOUR} < 0204    # AND it's before Tuesday 04
RewriteRule ^$ /maintenance.html [R=302,L]     # THEN redirect to maintenance page
```

You can find more examples [here](https://harrybailey.com/2015/08/htaccess-redirects-based-on-date-and-time/) and [here](http://codeinthehole.com/tips/date-conditional-redirects-with-mod_rewrite/)